# Using a for loop to create new data frame in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to use for loop in R to create separate data frames for my split result.
It may have better solutions but I am a beginner in R so any comments are appreciated.

'''
For example:
'''

```
For (i in 1:100)
{i<-df[[i]]}
```

'''
I expect to get something like

```
'1' equal to df[[1]]
'2' equal to df[[2]]
'3' equal to df[[3]]
.
.
.
'i' equal to df[[i]]
```

but it only gets the last `i`:

```
'100' which is equal to  df[[100]]
```

How can I get separate data frames for each `i`?

Comment: you are trying to create 100 objects in the environment.  INstead just keep the list as such or data.frame .and process whenever needed

Comment: [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) related/possible dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames)

Answer (score 1):

Since you require individual data frames, you can use the following to create a list of data frames:

```
df = NULL
for (i in 1:100) {
  df[[i]] = data.frame(i)
}
```

You can access each data frame in the list using the list index. For exampe

```
> df[[1]]
  i
1 1
> df[[2]]
  i
1 2
```

You can verify that each item in the list is a data frame

```
> str(df) # Partial output given
List of 100
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ i: int 1
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ i: int 2
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ i: int 3
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ i: int 4
.
.
.
```

Once you are more comfortable with R, a better way to achieve this result is to vectorize the task, such as by using `lapply`

```
df = lapply(1:100, data.frame)
```